# Why does this query work with HAVING but not with WHERE (there is no GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following query, I'm using the `x` and `y` as coordinates of objects in a two dimensional plane, And am trying to limit the results to only the objects which are within a radius of 80 units from the origin.

```
SELECT *,POW(x - 0,2) + POW(y - 0,2) AS distanceSquared
FROM objects

WHERE distanceSquared < 6400
```

The query here doesn't work for some reason, and mysql says `unknown column distanceSquared in where clause` . However, when I replace `WHERE` with `HAVING`, it works perfectly fine. Why? As far as I know, `HAVING` is only good for  columns on which aggregate functing have been used after a group by.

Comment: Both GROUP BY and HAVING clauses are optional. GROUP BY doesn't require HAVING; HAVING doesn't require GROUP BY. Although not widely known, this is part of SQL standards going back to at least 1992.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `distanceSquared` is defined in the `select` statement.

`where` clauses do not know about such variables, but `having` clauses do.

With no `group by`, the `having` just behaves like a `where` clause in MySQL.

This seems to be a fairly common practice in MySQL.  You can also express this as:

```
select o.*
from (SELECT *,POW(x - 0,2) + POW(y - 0,2) AS distanceSquared
      FROM objects
     ) o
WHERE distanceSquared < 6400;
```

In MySQL, though, the subquery is instantiated, meaning that the data is actually created and saved.  That makes such a query less performant than without a subquery.  Most other databases would optimize this correctly, and there would be no performance hit.

This use of the `having` clause without a `group by` is also a MySQL extension.  The query should be interpreted as an aggregation query that would return one row.  The `having` clause would then operate on that aggregation.